# Как включать/отключать disabled в <form> и сохранять результат без перерендера?

Tags: reactjs, form, forms

Есть форма с 3 полями, средняя форма **Email** по-умолчанию `disabled` через стейт.
Есть кнопка **Open/Close Input**, которая должна в реал-тайм менять её состояние с `true` на `false` и наоборот.
Через стейт не получается, т.к. стейт по клику измениться компонент переинициализируется и `inputDisabled` будет снова `true`. Через `ref`тоже пробовал, не получается, т.к. `ref` вообще не изменить не получается. Помогите)

```
export function Form() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [inputDisabled, setInputDisabled] = useState(true);

  console.log("pererender");

  function handleNameChange(event) {
    setName(event.target.value);
  }
  function handleEmailChange(event) {
    setEmail(event.target.value);
  }
  function handlePhoneChange(event) {
    setPhone(event.target.value);
  }

  const inputOpen = () => {
    setInputDisabled((prev) => !prev);
  };

  function handleSubmit() {
    console.log({
      name,
      email,
      phone,
    });
  }

  return (
    <form className="form__main-container">
      <div className="form__input-container">
        <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" onChange={handleNameChange} />
      </div>
      <div className="form__input-container">
        <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="email"
          name="email"
          onChange={handleEmailChange}
          disabled={inputDisabled}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form__input-container">
        <label htmlFor="phone">Phone:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="phone"
          name="phone"
          onChange={handlePhoneChange}
        />
      </div>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Submit
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => inputOpen()}>Open/Close Input</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Через стейт не получается, т.к. стейт по клику измениться компонент переинициализируется

Как вариант - добавить соответствующей кнопке "простой" тип `type='button'`...

```js
//
function Form() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
  const [phone, setPhone] = React.useState("");
  const [inputDisabled, setInputDisabled] = React.useState(true);

  function handleNameChange(event) {
    setName(event.target.value);
  }
  function handleEmailChange(event) {
    setEmail(event.target.value);
  }
  function handlePhoneChange(event) {
    setPhone(event.target.value);
  }

  const inputOpen = () => {
    setInputDisabled(prev => !prev);
  };

  function handleSubmit() {
    console.log({
      name,
      email,
      phone,
    });
  }

  return (
    <form className="form__main-container">
      <div className="form__input-container">
        <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" onChange={handleNameChange} />
      </div>
      <div className="form__input-container">
        <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="email"
          name="email"
          onChange={handleEmailChange}
          disabled={inputDisabled}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form__input-container">
        <label htmlFor="phone">Phone:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="phone"
          name="phone"
          onChange={handlePhoneChange}
        />
      </div>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Submit
      </button>
      <button type='button' onClick={inputOpen}>Open/Close Input</button>
    </form>
  );
}
const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<Form />);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="like_button_container"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо!! Боже, почему я забыл про этот атрибут... 
Осталось разобраться почему этот атрибут так кардинально меняет работу.

Comment: @ПавелАртамонов, не происходит отправка формы...